# Finding the area of an equilateral triangle using the Pythagorean theorem

Tags: triangles, pythagorean-triples

From an equilateral triangle $T$ where each side have a length of $L$. What is the area of $T$?

According to the [Wikipedia page of equilateral triangles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle), the area is $$A=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{4}L^2$$

I am trying to solve this problem by using the Pythagorean theorem, [as explained in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277872/equilateral-triangle-height-problem), I can split the triangle in half to try and get the height.

Using the Pythagorean theorem, $$L^2=(\dfrac{L}{2})^2 + H^2$$

I can then isolate $H$ with :

$$H=\sqrt{L^2-(\dfrac{L}{2})^2}$$

Using the $A=\dfrac{1}{2}bh$ formula. I could then conclude with :
$$A=\dfrac{L\sqrt{L^2-(\dfrac{L}{2})^2}}{2}$$

As said previously, the Wikipedia page shows something very different. What went wrong?

Comment: Why do you think those are different?

Comment: Factor the $L^2$ then pass it out.

Comment: $L^2-(L/2)^2=\frac{3L^2}{4}$

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses that adjust to their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. Please see [this tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) on how to typeset math on this site.

Comment: @Cedric Martens I corrected a stupid mistake in my answer. (Tired when I posted, I forgot we had $2$ right triangles. Please look at it again and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

With the Pythagorean theorem, you can find the altitude of an equilateral triangle by dropping a vertical line to split it. Then, the long side and half of the bottom are, respectively, the hypotenuse $C$ and a short leg $B$ of a right triangle. The vertical will be side $A$ of a right triangle where $A=\sqrt{C^2-\bigl{(}\frac{C}{2}\bigr{)}^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4C^2-C^2}{4}}=\frac{C\sqrt{3}}{2}$. The area of one triangle is $\frac{1}{2}A*B$ where $B=\frac{C}{2}$. However, we have two of these right triangles so the area is simply A*B. You should end up with
$area=A\cdot B=\frac{C\sqrt{3}}{2}\cdot\frac{C}{2}=\frac{C^2\sqrt{3}}{4}$.